# Warning: Attempt to present * on * whose view is not in the window hierarchy - swift

Tags: ios, swift, hierarchy, presentviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a `ViewController` *if* there is any saved data in the data model. But I get the following error:

> Warning: Attempt to present * on *whose view is not in the window hierarchy"

Relevant code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UserData")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    if(results.count <= 0){
        print("Inga resultat")
    } else {
        print("SWITCH VIEW PLOX")
        let internVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("internVC") as internViewController
        self.presentViewController(internVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I've tried different solutions found using Google without success.

Comment: Have you connected your ViewController in Storyboard? You are using a NavigationController here?

Comment: What to you mean if i have connected my `ViewController`in Storyboard? I am not using `NavigationController` @derdida

Comment: Try: self.addChildViewController(childController: UIViewController) in ViewDidLoad

Comment: This generates an error. It expects a member name or constructor call after "type name" (The `UIViewController` part). @derdida

Comment: Where did you wrote that? In ViewDidLoad of your MainViewController?

Comment: Yes. But Acey solved it, thanks a bunch for helping anyway. Cheers.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

At this point in your code the view controller's view has only been created but not added to any view hierarchy. If you want to present from that view controller as soon as possible you should do it in `viewDidAppear` to be safest.

Comment: If I put it in the viewDidAppear, then when I dismiss the presentedViewController, it will again call the viewDidAppear method and present the viewController again.I have a workaround of putting a conditional statement before presenting it, but is there any way instead of putting a conditional statement?

Comment: I would say that trying to present another modal right when a screen appears is odd behavior to start with, so a state bool is hardly the worst solution. At the same time, think about the root reason you are needing to display the modal and see if you can access that information.

Comment: If you do it in viewWillAppear, you will have the situation where it's in the middle of presenting when you start your presentation. An alternate would be to put it in viewWillAppear but use the transitionCoordinator property new in iOS 8 to add the code in the completion of the transition. More info can be found here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator_Protocol/index.html

Comment: I can't thank you enough. This just fixed my issue I've been trying to figure out the last several days.

Answer (score 36):

In objective c:
This solved my problem when presenting viewcontroller on top of mpmovieplayer

```
- (UIViewController*) topMostController
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    return topController;
}
```

Answer (score 36):

Swift 3

I had this keep coming up as a newbie and found that present loads modal views that can be dismissed but switching to root controller is best if you don't need to show a modal.

I was using this

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc  = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainAppStoryboard") as! TabbarController
present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Using this instead with my tabController:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let view = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainAppStoryboard") as UIViewController
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
//show window
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = view
```

Just adjust to a view controller if you need to switch between multiple storyboard screens.

Answer (score 20):

Swift 3.

Call this function to get the topmost view controller, then have that view controller present.

```
func topMostController() -> UIViewController {
    var topController: UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
        while (topController.presentedViewController != nil) {
            topController = topController.presentedViewController!
        }
        return topController
    }
```

Usage:

```
let topVC = topMostController()
let vcToPresent = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourVCStoryboardID") as! YourViewController
topVC.present(vcToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanx @Jacob Davis for this! I used it to present an alertController cause i was getting the Warning: Attempt to present....

Comment: This is very useful. some what am getting presenting controller But screen is not appearing . suddenly its get dismissed. Any other code needs to implement? please suggest

Answer (score 14):

for SWIFT

```
func topMostController() -> UIViewController {
    var topController: UIViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!
    while (topController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController!
    }
    return topController
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the only thing that solved this error for me.  I was trying to present a modal VC from a function triggered by a gesture recognizer, well after the view fully loaded (in Xcode 8 / iOS 10).   
Strangely, the `topController` returned by this function is the exact same VC as `self` in when trying to present directly using `self.presentViewController(myModalVC)`, but there is no view hierarchy error when I pass in the presenting VC using your function.

Answer (score 14):

You just need to perform a selector with a delay - (0 seconds works).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    perform(#selector(presentExampleController), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)
}

@objc private func presentExampleController() {
    let exampleStoryboard = UIStoryboard(named: "example", bundle: nil)
    let exampleVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExampleVC") as! ExampleVC
    present(exampleVC, animated: true) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got stuck in this problem for over an hour.

Comment: Thank... @objc  func presentExampleController()

Comment: I think it's an amazing answer!

Comment: That is a hack (which may work now), but will set you up for something that breaks in unexpected cases.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4

```
func topMostController() -> UIViewController {
    var topController: UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
    while (topController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController!
    }
    return topController
}
```

Comment: An explanation and example would be helpful @AllenWixted

Answer (score 5):

Use of main thread to present and dismiss view controller worked for me.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil) }
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error while was presenting controller after the user opens the deeplink.
I know this isn't the best solution, but if you are in short time frame here is a quick fix - just wrap your code in `asyncAfter`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.7, execute: { [weak self] in
                                navigationController.present(signInCoordinator.baseController, animated: animated, completion: completion)
                            })
```

It will give time for your presenting controller to call `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 2):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "test", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "teststoryboard") as UIViewController
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This seemed to work to make sure it's the top most view.

I was getting an error

> Warning: Attempt to present myapp.testController: 0x7fdd01703990 on myapp.testController: 0x7fdd01703690 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Hope this helps others with swift 3

Answer (score 2):

> For swift 3.0 and above

```
public static func getTopViewController() -> UIViewController?{
if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
{
  while (topController.presentedViewController != nil)
  {
    topController = topController.presentedViewController!
  }
  return topController
}
return nil}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.1**:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ID")
let appDeleg = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let root = appDeleg.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
root.pushViewController(mainViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried so many approches! the only useful thing is:

```
if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
{
  while (topController.presentedViewController != nil)
  {
    topController = topController.presentedViewController!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All implementation for topViewController here are not fully supporting cases when you have `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController`, for those two you need a bit different handling:

For `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController` you need a different implementation.

Here is code I'm using to get topMostViewController:

```
protocol TopUIViewController {
    func topUIViewController() -> UIViewController?
}

extension UIWindow : TopUIViewController {
    func topUIViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        if let rootViewController = self.rootViewController {
            return self.recursiveTopUIViewController(from: rootViewController)
        }

        return nil
    }

    private func recursiveTopUIViewController(from: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
        if let topVC = from?.topUIViewController() { return recursiveTopUIViewController(from: topVC) ?? from }
        return from
    }
}

extension UIViewController : TopUIViewController {
    @objc open func topUIViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        return self.presentedViewController
    }
}

extension UINavigationController {
    override open func topUIViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        return self.visibleViewController
    }
}

extension UITabBarController {
    override open func topUIViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        return self.selectedViewController ?? presentedViewController
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers relate to the situation where the view controller that should present a view 1) has not been added yet to the view hierarchy, or 2) is not the top view controller.
Another possibility is that an alert should be presented while another alert is already presented, and not yet dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

Swift Method, and supply a demo.

```
func topMostController() -> UIViewController {
    var topController: UIViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!
    while (topController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController!
    }
    return topController
}

func demo() {
    let vc = ViewController()
    let nav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc)
    topMostController().present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than finding top view controller, one can use

```
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.currentContext
```

Where viewController is the controller which you want to present
This is useful when there are different kinds of views in hierarchy like TabBar, NavBar, though others seems to be correct but more sort of hackish

The other presentation style can be found on [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle)