# MessagePeopleTableViewController: 0x7fb47dd44f80> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    dismiss(animated: true) {
        let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatPage")
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        print("111")

    }
}
```

**getting error while dismissing one view controller and moving to another viewcontroller by completionblock**
please help me in solving this problem, I referred site but still I got stuck here.

Comment: see this for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022756/warning-attempt-to-present-on-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy-s

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you are going to present "ChatPage" controller from current controller that is already dismissed. I think that this is the reason.

If your current controller is Modal, you can try something like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            dismiss(animated: true) {

        let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatPage")     

        //get access to presenting parent controller
        self.presentingViewController.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        print("111")

    }
}
```

Or save parent controller instance in current controller, but this is not good code actually.

If this will not work, the other way is to use a delegate that will call some method in parent controller to present something. It means that you should call self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil) from the controller that should present a new controller (in your case it is parent controller I guess), but not from controller that will be dismissed