# Creating a SwiftUI UIViewControllerRepresentable for a ViewController that doesn't have a ViewController Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, networking, swiftui, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I am trying to build a SwiftUI tvOS app.
As you can [see here](https://github.com/TheFirstPrototype/AppleTV-NetworkDiscovery-Swift/blob/features/swiftui-tv/BuildingACustomPeerToPeerProtocol/TicTacToe/SendingMessages/DDevicePickerView.swift), I am trying to create a SwiftUI View using a UIViewControllerRepresentable, specifically for the [DDDevicePickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicediscoveryui/dddevicepickerviewcontroller).

However, I noticed that there is no `DDDevicePickerViewControllerDelegate` while I was trying to implement it, which is needed according to [Paul Hudson's tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/wrapping-a-uiviewcontroller-in-a-swiftui-view). How can I use the DevicePickerView in SwiftUI?

I tried to use this code to create it, so when I use it, I just get a black screen with no errors in the logs:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import DeviceDiscoveryUI

public struct DDevicePickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let viewController: DDDevicePickerViewController

    public init() {
        // Create the view controller for the device picker.
        let devicePicker = DDDevicePickerViewController(browseDescriptor: .applicationService(name: "TicTacToe"),
                                                              parameters: applicationServiceParameters())
        self.viewController = devicePicker!
    }

    public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> DDDevicePickerViewController {
        let gkVC = viewController
        return gkVC
    }

    public func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: DDDevicePickerViewController, context: Context) {
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Also related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74647385/unable-to-connect-watchos-to-the-tvos-with-the-networking-framework

Comment: Having a delegate is not necessary for a `UIViewRepresentable`. That tutorial only shows a delegate because the image picker has it. You should update your question to show what you have tried and how it wasn't working if you ran into actual problems.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks for the feedback, updated with code, and result of code

Comment: That UIViewControllerRepresentable implementation is not correct

Comment: @malhal what's wrong with it? Can you please share a resource I can follow?

Comment: makeUIViewController needs to init the VC or get it out of a coordinator. In SwiftUI, the structs shouldn't store objects because they are immediately lost.

Comment: @malhal I init the VC inside the init of the View but it doesn’t work even when I init the VC in makeUIViewController. How would I be able to get it out of a coordinator? I have no delegate for that view controller.

Comment: I believe you don't need a coordinator here you can use a view controller. In `makeUIViewController` return a vanilla `UIViewController`. Add an `@Binding var isPresented: Bool` and in `updateUIViewController` if the bool is true then init a devicePicker and do viewController.show(devicePicker), if the bool is false then dismiss it. That's how we normally do it however the result being async is going to make it harder.

Comment: I've added some code in an answer to demonstrate this

Comment: @malhal I have no idea how you found DevicePicker, but it's worked! It's also the most generic, least descriptive name

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI already has a wrapper [DevicePicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicediscoveryui/devicepicker?language=_4)

But if you want to wrap it yourself, start with something like this and then you just have to figure out how to get the async `endpoint` result. It is quite unusual to have view controllers be async like this.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import DeviceDiscoveryUI

public struct DevicePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool

    public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        UIViewController()
    }

    public func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        if isPresented {
             if uiViewController.presentedViewController != nil {
                 return
             }
             
             let = picker DDDevicePickerViewController(browseDescriptor: .applicationService(name: "TicTacToe"), parameters: applicationServiceParameters())
              uiViewController.present(picker, animated: !context.transaction.disablesAnimations)
        }
        else {
            uiViewController.presentedViewController?.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ! Thanks a lot. I was getting a runtime non crash error (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022756/warning-attempt-to-present-on-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy-s) at `uiViewController.present` so I had to wrap it in DispatchQueue.main.async {...}. Either way the app gets stuck on a black screen after the present -,-
So that did do anything either

It might be that its waiting for the `let endpoint = try await picker.endpoint` to do some work?

There's no documentation anywhere of this being done in swiftUI but I might have to give up

Comment: Yeh working around this async thing is going to be a challenge. I found one example on Github but it's for UIKit https://github.com/TheFirstPrototype/AppleTV-NetworkDiscovery-Swift/blob/aca9e517e31f2b2710de1469ad5b37bb9ecd2e9d/BuildingACustomPeerToPeerProtocol/TicTacToe/TicTacToe-tvOS/Views/PeerListViewController.swift

Comment: yeah that’s my code lol  It’s from the WWDC example code which uses UIKit